# How to Illustrate Relationship between Adjusted Variable and Variable of Interest

Tags: regression, correlation, data-visualization

I'll give an example.

In a simple correlation, blood pressure is associated with body fat.

However, I want to adjust %body fat for age and sex. So, in SAS, PROC CORR I use age and sex as partial variables and the association remains significant between blood pressure and body fat(adjusted).

How can I illustrate this in a graph (i.e. blood pressure vs %bodyfat (adjusted))?

My first though was to use a linear regression (PROC REG/PROC GLM) with %bodyfat as the dependent variable and age, sex as the independent/quantitative variables and then output the residuals. Add the mean of %bodyfat to the residuals and then plot this as my y values.

Is this appropriate or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Have you considered a conditional independence network? What would the plot you are suggesting have on the $x$- and $y$-axis? Adding the mean would just offset the location of each residual by the same amount from zero.

Comment: Adding the mean would just give some interpretability.

On the x I would have blood pressure and on the y i would have adjusted body fat ( for age and sex)

Comment: If you want to do that, you should add the intercept instead, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you only have two variables you're adjusting for, one of which is a 2-category factor, the easiest way to visualize the whole thing would just be by using some colouring and symbols:

```
# simulate data
set.seed(1234)
age <- round(rnorm(30, 40, 10))
sex <- round(runif(30, 0, 1))
bodyfat <- rnorm(30, 10 + 5 * sex + age / 10, 3)
bloodpressure <- rnorm(30, 55 + bodyfat * 2 + age / 10, 5)

# plot original with color and pch set to other variables
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "black", "red"))(30)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
plot(bloodpressure ~ bodyfat, col = cols[order(age)], pch = sex + 17)
legend("bottomright", legend = c("male", "female"), pch = 17:18)
```

[image: original]

You could add a colour scale to your legend for age.

---

Alternatively, you could adjust bodyfat for age and sex, although **this loses its easy interpretation**. If you want to adjust as you propose in your question—by regressing body fat on age and sex—you should add the *intercept* of this model to the residuals, not the mean.

This is equivalent to subtracting $\beta_1 \cdot \text{age}$ and $\beta_2 \cdot \text{sex}$ from the body fat percentage in:

$$\text{body fat percentage} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot \text{age} + \beta_2 \cdot{sex} + \epsilon$$

That would look like this:

```
# plot blood pressure vs adjusted bodyfat
LM <- lm(bodyfat ~ age + sex)
adjusted_BF <- (coef(LM)[1] + resid(LM))
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(bloodpressure ~ bodyfat)
plot(bloodpressure ~ adjusted_BF)
```

[image: adjusted]

As expected, the relationship observed in the right scatter plot is slightly weaker after adjusting for the effects of age and sex.

---

**However**, looking at partial correlations is more like adjusting *both* variables for the remaining variables:

```
LM2 <- lm(bloodpressure ~ age + sex)
adjusted_BP <- coef(LM2)[1] + resid(LM2)
plot(adjusted_BP ~ adjusted_BF)
```

[image: partial]

But again, be careful not to mislead your readers with this, as these axes no longer represent blood pressure and body fat.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent explanation and detailing of the different methods. I have one follow up question -- I've came across some papers in my field that say this "in linear models adjusted for age and sex, blood pressure was associated with %bodyfat (r=0.45, P<0.01)". How did they obtain a Pearson's R from a linear model?
Thanks for your insight.

Comment: By *linear models adjusted for age and sex*, they likely mean $\text{BP} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot \text{BF} + \beta_2 \cdot \text{age} + \beta_3 \cdot \text{sex} + \epsilon$. Authors often include the coefficient of determination ($R^2$) as a means for the reader to judge the variance in $\text{BP}$ explained by the model. Maybe this is what they meant? You can calculate it as 1 minus the residual sum of squares divided by the total sum of squares: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination

Comment: Understood, and that makes sense.

What do you think of this [response](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327857/plot-to-show-bivariate-relationship-from-a-multiple-regression?rq=1)?

Comment: I think the responder's second suggestion makes sense. That is, "fix" the effects of the covariates/confounders using the mean and then calculate the Y values with values of my actual predictor of interest

Comment: Setting the covariates to a suitable value only makes sense if such a value exists. For age you could argue that most people are around a certain age (like the mean), but for sex, would it really make sense to take the mean of the dummy variable?

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't - but this is a graph to show the "r" relationship for graphical purposes in a scientific publication.

Comment: I don't think that is standard practice, but it can't hurt if you clearly describe what the figure represents. Personally, I would then go for the latter of the three plots I suggested in my answer. Let me know if anything remains unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough data for each age-group you are interested in, "*facets*" may be a better way to convey your message than the first graph proposed by @Frans Rodenburg.

**Simulate data**

```
set.seed(1234)
age <- round(rnorm(1000, 40, 10))
sex <- round(runif(1000, 0, 1))
bodyfat <- rnorm(1000, 10 + 5 * sex + age / 10, 3)
bloodpressure <- rnorm(1000, 55 + bodyfat * 2 + age / 10, 5)
```

**Data transformation**

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(bodyfat, bloodpressure, age, sex)
data <- data %>%
          mutate(age_group = case_when(age < 25 ~ "0 to 25",
                                       age >= 25 & age < 40 ~ "25 to 40",
                                       age >= 40 & age < 50 ~ "40 to 50",
                                       age >= 50 & age < 60 ~ "50 to 60",
                                       age >= 60 ~ "60 and over"
                                       )) %>%
          mutate(sex = case_when(sex == 0 ~ "female",
                                 sex == 1 ~ "male"))
```

**Data visualization through facets**

```
ggplot(data, aes(bodyfat, bloodpressure)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(age_group ~ sex)
```

[image]